# Reading a matrix from text file and storing it in 2-d array

Tags: c

I am trying to read a text file formatted as a matrix and store it into a 2-d array in C. But I keep getting segmentation faults. I am not sure if I used fgetc correctly and how to fix it.

Command:

```
./exec number filename
```

Text file:

```
00000
01100
00100
00100
00000
```

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    char *mapping = malloc(strlen(argv[2]) + 1);
    strcpy(mapping,argv[2]);
    FILE *file = fopen(mapping, "r");
    
    int c;
    int matrix[5][5] = {0};

    for(int i =0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            c = fgetc(file);
            if(c == '1')
            {
                matrix[i][j] = 1;
            }
            else if(c == '0')
            {
                matrix[i][j] = 0;
            }
            else if(c == EOF)
            {
                return -1; 
            }

        }

    }


}
```

Edit: I used fscanf as below, but it is giving me the output, which is incorrect.

```
01100100100000000000000000000000
```

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    char *mapping = malloc(strlen(argv[2]) + 1);
    strcpy(mapping,argv[2]);
    FILE *file = fopen(mapping, "r");

    char c;
    int matrix[5][5];

    for(int i =0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            fscanf(file, "%d", &c);

        }
    }
    fclose(file);

    for(int i =0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            printf("%d", matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }



    return 0;
```

Comment: You should use `argc` to confirm the presence of comand line arguments before you access `argv`, you should also check the return value of `fopen` to confirm the file was correctly accessed.

Comment: The variable `n` is never used, if it was I would advise the use of `strtol` instead of `atoi`.

Comment: Also don't forget the newline character at the end of each line, it will be read by `fgetc` and it will rob you an iteration.

Comment: since you already know the dimensions why not use `fscanf`? It will ommit newlines that are causing the problems now ;)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I used fscanf, but it is not getting me the result I wanted. I was wondering if you could help to check why it is still incorrect?